# Libraries with custom attributes conflicting

Tags: android, attributes, libraries

I am trying to use Shimmer library and a [Slider View library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) together.

Unfortunately, there's a custom attributes in both libraries that is conflicting: I am getting a `duplicate attribute found` error.

I have read that this is a bug and there are no solutions as of now and we cant create custom attributes within the context of each library. But is there any other way around it apart from me implementing the slider view myself?

`````
Android resource compilation failed 
app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4619: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/shape' with config ''.
\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4619: error: resource previously defined here.
\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: error: file failed to compile.````
`````

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an workaround for that issue. However, I'm not sure if you can do that due to licensing.

I didn't test it. Not sure if it will work. But I think you can try. If that does not work, let me know and I delete the answer.

To avoid that error, you can resort to the fact that you have access to the source code of the `AndroidImageSlider`. This way, instead of adding that library as an AAR file, you can import the source code as a module.
This way, you can rename the `attr/shape` and it will be re-compiled as part of your project.

1) Remove the `AndroidImageSlider` from your project (from build.gradle etc)

2) Then, create a new module called "library" (`File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> + -> Android Library`)

3) This will create a new folder to your project `<ProjectPath>/library`

4) Download the Library Source (using git or as a zip file) and replace the content of the library folder with content from library folder that you downloaded (you can ignore all other folders... You can replace the files of same name).

5) Remove file `library/gradle-mvn-push.gradle` and remove following line from: `library/build.gradle`:

```
 apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

6) Add following lines to your `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(":library")
    ...
}
```

7) Sync and Rebuild your project.

8) Open the file `./library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml` and rename the atribute `shape` (`customShape` for example).

9) Try to build again. Some errors may happen since you renamed that attribute. Fix them.

10) You can add the view to your layout as follows:

This will allow you to compile your project. The downside is that you are responsible to fix/update the library by yourself. On the other hand, you have control over the libraries `build.gradle` and then, you can update the build tools version, support library version etc.

Anyway, this may help you

Comment: any  other solution ?